# Are injective operators invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am little worried about the notion of invertible operators.

Let $E,F$ be two Banach spaces and $A:D(A)\subset E \to F$  be an operator.
We have the following lemma:

```
  If A is closed and injective, then its inverse is closed.
```

We say that $A$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is bijective map. i.e there exists an operator $B:F \to D(A)$ such that $BAu=u$ for every $u \in D(A)$ and $ABv=v$ for every $v \in F$.

In the lemma they are not mentioning surjectivity!

Comment: They may be considering its inverse as a partial function.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Its inverse from the range of $A$ ?

Answer (score 1):

When $A : D(A) \to F$ is injective, it's bijective on the range $R(A)$, and then you can define its inverse $A^{-1}: R(A) \to D(A)$.

Comment: yeap i think that what he means

Comment: Sure, which reference is this?